# Why import works in this ROS python script

Tags: python, import, ros

I am working with [ROS](https://www.ros.org/) packages and coming from [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) tutorial. This **import statement surprisingly works** given the absence of `AddTwoIntsResponse` anywhere in the current working directory or any other directory listed in *PATH*. Also how come a *.srv* gets imported?

```py
# add_two_ints_server.py
from beginner_tutorials.srv import AddTwoInts, AddTwoIntsResponse
```

The current working directory is `~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/srv`

This is my ROS directory layout:

```
catkin_ws
|-- src
|   `-- beginner_tutorials
|       |-- scripts
|       |   `-- add_two_ints_server.py
|       `-- srv
|           `-- AddTwoInts.srv
|-- build
`-- devel
```

The contents of **AddTwoInts.srv** are:

```
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
```

According to my understanding this should throw an `ImportError: cannot import name 'AddTwoIntsResponse'`, **but it doesn't**. Importing any other file say: `from beginner_tutorials.srv import foo` throws an *ImportError*.

Where is my understanding going wrong?

Comment: Since this appears to be part of a tutorial, can you please link to it in your question?

Comment: Can you please clarify what parts you *do* understand? In normal Python, ``AddTwoInts`` would also not be importable since it is a ``.srv`` file, not a ``.py`` file.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have fair bit of knowledge in Python. Yes, I wondered how AddTwoInts could be imported. I missed to put that in the question. I have added the tutorial link too.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, can you please help me with this.

Comment: I'm afraid not. As hinted, you do not import ``.py`` files but ``.src`` files – meaning there is an [import hook doing module discovery and generation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks). Either you accept that ``AddTwoIntsResponse`` is importable *just like ``AddTwoInts``* (because magic), or you need an in-depth explanation of how import hooks work to turn arbitrary data into source code. Frankly, import hooks are not something to explain just for fun.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think you just gave a good explanation of why this works. I will try my best to research a bit more on import hooks. I don't mind generating a few reputation points for you if you got the time to post the earlier comment as an answer. It does give me head-start to solve my problem.

Comment: No worries, if my comments helped you that's good already. Once you have groked the problem, consider to write a self-answer. I think this is an interesting problem and there doesn't seem to be any proper explanation in public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
|-- src
|   `-- beginner_tutorials
|       |-- scripts
|       |   `-- add_two_ints_server.py
|       `-- srv
|           `-- AddTwoInts.srv
|-- build
|-- devel // this is where your modules are imported from
```

When you build the package using catkin_make, 'catkin` generates the relevant python files for your service type defined in .srv file and puts them under catkin_ws/devel/lib/**your-python-version**/dist-packages/**package-name**/srv.

If your workspace is sourced, catkin_ws/devel/lib/**your-python-version**/dist-packages/ is already added to your PYTHONPATH and that is how you are able to import them successfully.

In case of the tutorial package that you are using, imports may work even when you haven't sourced your current catkin-directory, if you have the binaries of the tutorials installed. This way the python modules reside under /opt/ros/**ros-version**/lib/**your-python-version**/dist-packages/ and that is again part of the PYTHONPATH. (If ROS env is available)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. In the question comments, @MisteraMiyagi mentioned about _import hooks_. Is this a short way of saying the work done by ```catkin_make``` and adding it to PATH?

Comment: @maddypie I dont think so. ROS python imports are not that complex.